# Why is "docker" command not being found when run from gradle?

Tags: docker, build.gradle

I have a task called buildImage in my build.gradle file:

```
task buildImage(type: Exec) {
  ...
  executable 'docker'
  blah
}
```

When I run the command `./gradlew buildImage`, I see an error:

```
Could not start 'docker' in directory mydir: error=2, No such file or directory
```

However, I can simply run the command "docker" and it works.

```
% which docker
/usr/local/bin/docker
```

Why is it not working when I invoke docker through gradle? How do I fix it?

Note that I can make it work by specifying the full path:

```
task buildImage(type: Exec) {
  ...
  executable '/usr/local/bin/docker'
  blah
}
```

But this is a team project and everyone is expected to have docker in the path.

If it helps, I am running this on Mac M1. Thanks.

Edit:  Adding more info.

I added the following line in build.gradle:

```
println(System.getenv("PATH"))
```

The path that is printed is:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

It is missing /usr/local/bin in the path.

How do I add this to the path?

Also, I don't know where it is getting this path from. When I run "echo $PATH" in the terminal window, I see a much longer path.

Comment: have you tried to provide the full path to the executable? also the environment running gradle might be different from yours, but i'm just guessing, provide more info.